# Ansible: skip the step based on a variable value

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

Following code should skip if the Ansible variable is set to `https: off` in variables yml file.

`default_setup.yml`:

```
 # Other info
 ansible_cache_dir: /var/cache/ansible
 https: off
```

`provision.yml`:

```
 ---
 - hosts: webclient
   vars_files:
   - default_setup.yml

 - name: Update server.xml tomcat https conf
   template:
       src: conf_files/tomcat_server.xml
       dest: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-{{ tomcat_ver }}/conf/server.xml
   become: true
   when: "{{ https }}" == "on"
   notify: restart tomcat
```

When I play this Ansible `provision.yml` getting the following error, even though I have added the quote("")

```
  ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


    The error appears to have been in '/home/centos/check-tomcat/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml': line 24, column 23, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

 The offending line appears to be:

  become: true
  when: "{{ https }}" == "on"
                  ^ here
 We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
 missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
 start a value. For instance:

      with_items:
         - {{ foo }}

   Should be written as:

      with_items:
         - "{{ foo }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- `off` in YAML is a boolean value (synonym of `false` and `no`), so if you leave the `https` definition as is, it's enough to use the following condition:

  ```
  when: not https
  ```
- if you'd change `https` to a string, i.e. with:

  ```
  https: "off"
  ```

  then the condition might be:

  ```
  when: https == "off"
  ```